# Добавить фон для первой строки пункта списка `<li>` содержащего внутри себя другой список

Tags: html, css

Требуется чтобы фон, определяемый классом `active`, применялся только к первой строке пункта списка `<li>` содержащего внутри себя другой список, а в остальных случаях обрабатывался по умолчанию (как определено в стандарте):

```css
.active {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="active">sub li1
        <ul>
            <li>child1</li>
            <li>child2</li>
            <li class="active">child3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>sub li2
        <ul>
            <li>child1</li>
            <li>child2</li>
            <li class="active">child3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Желаемый результат[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/c86uLrsv/

Comment: @soledar10, костыльно конечно :) Есть вариант использовать `li .active:before {content: '•'; background: yellow;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подобных вещей можно использовать универсальные HTML-элементы, такие как `<div>` и `<span>`:

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="active">sub li1</div>
    <ul>
      <li>child1</li>
      <li>child2</li>
      <li class="active">child3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>sub li2
    <ul>
      <li>child1</li>
      <li>child2</li>
      <li class="active">child3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

https://jsfiddle.net/su8cu5dL/

Comment: Есть и сниппет и ссылка на jsfiddle. Это хорошо )

Answer (score 1):

если правильно понял, то можно так сделать:

```
ul > li:nth-child(3)
    {
        background-color: yellow;
        color: blue;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .active
    {
        background-color: yellow;
        color: blue;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

<ul>
    <li><div class="active">sub li1</div>
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> sub li2
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

попробуй к `ul:nth-last-child` добавить

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/88354)

Comment: @MaxZS это вполне похоже на вариант решения, по крайней мере направление. Если вы видите ошибку, пожалуйста объясните, в чём она состоит.

Comment: @guitarhero Не могли бы вы привести минимальный работающий пример решения? К вашим услугам сниппеты, это встроенный аналог jsfiddle для демонстрации кода прямо в ответе. Посмотрите, как это в соседнем ответе сделано: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/535486/edit